# tracert command return Request timed out

Tags: ping, network-discovery

I am trying to understand how tracert works,

1. I did a `ping www.google.co.nz`, found out Google's server IP is 172.217.25.131
2. `tracer 172.217.25.131`
3. I got the following screen of information

[image]

Can I please ask why there are three Request timed out?

- Are step 3,4,5 failed attempts on one router or on three different routers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract from Microsoft Support [How to Use TRACERT to Troubleshoot TCP/IP Problems in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows)

> The TRACERT diagnostic utility determines the route to a destination
>   by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo packets to
>   the destination. In these packets, TRACERT uses varying IP
>   Time-To-Live (TTL) values. Because each router along the path is
>   required to decrement the packet's TTL by at least 1 before forwarding
>   the packet, the TTL is effectively a hop counter. When the TTL on a
>   packet reaches zero (0), the router sends an ICMP "Time Exceeded"
>   message back to the source computer.
>
> TRACERT sends the first echo packet with a TTL of 1 and increments the
>   TTL by 1 on each subsequent transmission, until the destination
>   responds or until the maximum TTL is reached. The ICMP "Time Exceeded"
>   messages that intermediate routers send back show the route. Note
>   however that some routers silently drop packets that have expired
>   TTLs, and these packets are invisible to TRACERT.

So you can see that tracert rely on the router sending back an ICMP message "Time Exceeded".

Many routers on the Internet

- either are configured to not send ICMP message, those routers won't answer to ping
- either silently drop a TTL expired packet (but may respond to ping)

In both case, tracert doesn't receive any answer and display "Request time out".